# Where's the most appropriate place to ask about the efficacy of various documentation formats?

Tags: discussion

I was looking for a technical writing or documentation-writing stack, but didn't see one. Tips would be appreciated.

For example, [Is there any research about the efficacy of illustration and example placement in procedure writing?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/q/16015/5232)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Writers!  Technical writing is on-topic here.  I'm not quite sure what you mean by "documentation models", but chances are your questions fit here.  Ask away!  (Or if you're still not sure, could you add a couple example question titles to your question here so we'll have something more concrete to discuss?)

Comment: Just posted it...I think I was pretty clear with what I'm looking for. Perhaps documentation FORMATs would have been a better question in meta (and it is now), and I flagged it with "formatting" so....

Comment: Yes, that's on-topic here.  Thanks for asking, and I hope we're able to come up with the research you asked about.

Answer (score 1):

Your example question is on-topic here at Writers, but the [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com) *might* provide an answer more focused on user experience design (though from a *brief* look at tags and question lists there seems to be a very heavy focus on interactive media/human-computer interface). It might be worthwhile to ask this question on their [Meta](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com).